# recover chef node configure from server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chef

Does anyone know to to retrieve chef node configs from an open source chef server? I need to move node configs that where managed by an old chef server (cloud instance) that didn't update properly to a new chef server.

I know how to get them on to a new chef server when I have the node.json file. I am just wondering if there is some place on the file system of the server I can go to retrieve them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the old server is still running, you can use `knife node show -f json nodename` to get them.  I believe there are a few knife plugins that will give you `backup` type commands as well.  Those would help you avoid running one command per node.

As for access to the node data outside a running server, I'm pretty sure the nodes are stored in a database, so it would not be trivial to retrieve them, but you could theoretically query the database.

Answer (score 0):

Node data is stored in the Chef server database in a format that isn't trivial to extract. If your Chef Server is still functional then you can simply run `knife download nodes/NODENAME.json` for a particular node or simply `knife download nodes` to download all of your nodes data to a nodes directory.

If your Chef server is no longer functioning properly then you may want to open a support ticket by emailing support@chef.io or browsing to https://www.chef.io/support/tickets/ and they will be happy to help you as best as they can.